# Null Pointer Except

Tags: nullpointerexception

My code compiles just fine in eclipse, but when I run it in linux in the command prompt I get a null pointer except on line 19. null is not used anywhere in my code. please help

```
public class lab4 {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (isr);

        ArrayList<String> studentInfo;
        studentInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

        String  students = br.readLine();       
        String [] answers = students.split ("\\s+"); 

        while(!students.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")){           
           students = br.readLine();                                                        
            studentInfo.add(students);
        }

        String [] s0 = studentInfo.get(0).split ("\\s+");
```

This is the problem area it keeps pointing me to:

```
      while(!students.equalsIgnoreCase("zzzz")){           
           students = br.readLine();                                                        
            studentInfo.add(students);
        }
```

Comment: Add if(br.readLine() != null) before doing read from buffer inside the While loop.

Comment: I added that code and it still does the same thing?

Comment: Actually add if((student = br.readline()) != null)  in place of students = br.readLine(); Also you also need to do this null check  in the earlier section of the code where you ar reading from buffer for the first time

Answer (score 0):

[BufferedReader.readLine may return null if the end of the stream has be reached.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29)

Comment: Should I change to the scanner class?

Comment: You could, checking for null is also an option, depends if you prefer working with exception or nulls.